# how to initialize the array of pointers to a structure to zero

Tags: c, linux, pointers, structure

I am allocating memory for array of pointers to structure through malloc and want to initialize it with zero like mentioned below  . Assuming the structure contains member of type int and char [] (strings) ? so how can i zero out this struct.

Code : suppose i want to allocate for 100

```
struct A **a = NULL;
a = (struct **)malloc(sizeof( (*a) * 100);
for(i=1; i < 100; i++)
     a[i] = (struct A*)malloc(sizeof(a));
```

Also please explain me why is it necessary to initialize with zero .

Platform : Linux , Programing language : C

I know we can use memset or bzero . I tried it bt it was crashing , may be i was noy using it properly so pls tell me the correct way .

Comment: The only thing that indicates that this is C++ is the cast of the return value of `malloc`. You should probably be using `vector`, or at least `new[]`

Comment: arrays in C are 0-origin, e.g., if `arr` is an array, `arr[0]` is the first element of the array. In your code example, `a[0]` is never initialized.

Comment: C or C++? Choose one, they are different languages.

Comment: Oh no, it's the elusive C/C++ animal...

Comment: @john: This question has completely different answers if you are using C or if you are using C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `C` arrays are zero-based, not one-based. Next, you are allocating only enough space to hold one pointer, but you are storing 100 pointers into it. Are you trying to allocate 100 `A`s, or are you trying to allocate 100 sets of 100 `A`s each? Finally, the `malloc` inside your loop allocates space for the `sizeof a`, not `sizeof (struct A)`.

I'll assume that you are trying to allocate an array of 100 pointers to `A`, each pointer pointing to a single `A`.

Solutions: You could use [`calloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc):

```
struct A **a;
/* In C, never cast malloc(). In C++, always cast malloc() */
a = malloc(100 * sizeof( (*a)));
for(i=0; i < 100; i++)
    a[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(struct A));
```

Or, you could use [`memset`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset):

```
struct A **a;
a = malloc(100 * sizeof(*a));
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  a[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
  memset(a[i], 0, sizeof(struct A));
}
```

---

You ask "why is it necessary to initialize with zero?" It isn't. The relevant requirement is this: you must assign a value to your variables or initialize your variable before you use them for the first time. That assignment or initialization might be zero, or it might be `47` or it might be `"John Smith, Esq"`. It just has to be *some* valid assignment.

As a matter of convenience, you might choose to initialize all of your members of `struct A` to zero, which you can do in one single operation (`memset` or `calloc`). If zero is not a useful initial value for you, you could initialize the structure members by hand, for example:

```
struct A **a;
a = malloc(100 * sizeof(*a));
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  a[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
  a[i]->index = i;
  a[i]->small_prime = 7;
  strcpy(a[i]->name, name_database[i]);
}
```

As long as you never refer to the value of an uninitialized and unassigned variable, you are good.

Answer (score 6):

Use of calloc would be most in line with the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memset()` to set the whole array to `0`

OTOH,

```
a = (struct **)malloc(sizeof( (a*)));
for(i=1; i < 100; i++)
     a[i] = (struct*)malloc(sizeof(a) * 100);
```

is wrong, because you have just created one element of `a *` but in the next line when the loop goes to 2nd iteration, it will access illegal memory. So to allocate `100` elements of `a *`, your first `malloc()` should be as follows

```
a = (struct **)malloc(sizeof(a *) * 100);
```

The correct code (including error handling) would more or less will look as follows:

```
if ((a = (struct **)malloc(sizeof(a*) * 100)) == NULL) {
    printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
    return -1;
}

for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
    if ((a[i] = (struct*)malloc(sizeof(a) * 100)) == NULL) {
        printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(a[i], 0, 100);
}
```

or as an alternative to `malloc()` and `memset()`, you can use `calloc()`

Comment: It will do illegal accesses as soon as it gets to 1.

Comment: @john If you find my answer any useful, please feel free to upvote! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need many malloc's, one calloc is enough:

```
  int i;
  struct A **a = calloc(100,sizeof**a+sizeof*a),*mem=a+100;
  for(i=0;i<100;++i)
  {
    a[i]=&mem[i];
  }
  ...
  free(a);  /* and you only need ONE free */
```